# How do you permenantly set number of lines shown in pdb?

Tags: python, pdb

I can use `l` during run time to show more lines before and after the current line to be executed in pdb, but can we do this permanently in a script or via command-line option?

```
ywong:tmp ywong$ python tests.py
> /private/tmp/tests.py(23)<module>()
-> unittest.main()
(Pdb) l
 18             self.assertEqual(1,1)
 19
 20     if __name__ == "__main__":
 21         import pdb
 22         pdb.set_trace()
 23  ->     unittest.main()
 24         #unittest.main(testRunner=MyRunner)
[EOF]
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set up you own function which creates a custom debugger by instantiating the `pdb.Pdb` object and executing the `list` command before invoking the `pdb` interactive prompt.

You can create the custom debugger invocation function as follows :

```
import pdb, sys

def auto_list_debug():
    # Create an instance of the Pdb class
    my_pdb = pdb.Pdb()
    my_pdb.reset()

    # Execute your list command before invoking the interactive prompt
    my_pdb.cmdqueue.append('l')

    # Invoke the interactive prompt with the current frame
    my_pdb.interaction(sys._getframe().f_back, None)
```

Use this function instead of `pdb.set_trace()`

```
for i in range(5):
    auto_list_debug()
```